# Some questions about how IPTABLES works

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, squid

I am building a 4G proxy server from this tutorial:
https://learnproxy.altervista.org/create-your-own-mobile-4g-proxies-for-instagram-tutorial-2020/

In an excerpt of the tutorial, it is advised to create a script to make some routes in the ip tables of linux, but I am relatively new in the matter of networks and I am trying to better understand how it all works. If anyone can help me, guiding me better how these command lines work, I will be very grateful, the script in question is as follows:

```
sudo ifconfig usb0 192.168.0.100
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev usb0 src 192.168.0.100 table gw1
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev usb0 table gw1
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.0.100/32 table gw1
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.0.100/32 table gw1
```

Remembering that previously a line containing 1 gw1 was added in the **/etc/iproute2/rt_tables** file

And my question is: what do these command lines do exactly?

I have a ZTE MF823 and it can only be recognized and used by the squid (Proxy Server) if this routing is done through iptables, if I direct the ip of the modem right after it is plugged in, the squid gives a 503 error (example below) .

I also tried to add, for example, a share via cellphone usb that follows the same structure as the modem, I made the identical configuration and it does not recognize the cell phone's internet, I tried using the same ip range 192.168.0.X and I also tried in the same way which is originally attributed when I plug the cell phone 192.168.42.X and both got the same error message, even following the script above.

SQUID configuration excerpt:

```
http_port 4000
acl port4000 myportname 4000
http_access allow port4000
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.0.190 port4000
```

Squid Error Example

> 1632201093.105 86 x.x.x.x NONE/503 0 CONNECT i.instagram.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- -

Comment: Hello FelipeGabriel and welcome to unix.SE. **1)** > _"what do these command lines do exactly?"_ < Just out of curiosity, do you have the man page facility installed on your machine ?  You have a mother lode of documentation at your fingertips. It might be a good place to start.  **2)** _"ip range 192.168.0.X"_ ????   Do you mean `192.168.0.0/24` ? **LBNL** please ask only one question per post.

Comment: ip range 192.168.0.X represents any ip between 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254, I believe it is the same as 192.168.0.0/24

Comment: All this is about iproute2 (and ip ROUTING tables) not about iptables. Then squid should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: Got it friend, thank you, I'm going to research a little about iproute2